# sum the range of two inputs[python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, range, arithmetic-expressions

This script will accept two whole number inputs .
first input will always be (-) than the second.
script will display sum of every other whole number inputs.

script will not print any other text to the console other than the result of the operation.

here's the code i've written - so far i'm able to accept input but it produces an infinite loop and doesn't sum.

thanks

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

# user inputs digits
start = int(input())
stop = int(input())

# sum the range of above
while start < stop:
    print(sum for i in range(start, stop, 2))
```

Comment: Did you mean to use built-in `sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your problem `start` will always be less than `stop`, so the `while` loop never exits. Instead you can keep a variable that starts at `start` and increments by `2` until reaching `stop`.

```
# user inputs digits
start = int(input())
stop = int(input())

i = start
total = 0
while i < stop:
    total += i
    i += 2
```

For conciseness, this can simply be done with

```
total = sum(range(start, stop, 2))
```

Comment: thanks! that did it, i forgot to mention the range should include the final int but easily fixed. big help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum the range, then you don't even need a loop, as the `range` basically acts as your loop:

```py
# user inputs digits
start = int(input())
stop = int(input())

# sum the range of above
print(sum(range(start, stop, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `start` is always smaller than `stop` so of course the loop always runs.
If it was the other way around it would not even run once.

You have a `for` loop inside a `while` and that can be avoided as well:

```py
# user inputs digits
start = int(input())
stop = int(input())

# sum the range of above
result = 0
for i in range(start, stop, 2):
    result += i
```

Or, even better,

`result = sum(range(start, stop, 2))`

Comment: this appears to take 5 and increase the steps between the number over the course of 5 iterations to 9 when user inputs 5 and 9. the code should produce the number 7(two steps up) with a result of 21.

Comment: If you input 5 and 9 the code will sum 5+7+9. Is this not what you want?

Comment: My bad, `range` is not inclusive of the `stop` value, so it will sum 5+7 only. If you want 9 too, just replace `stop` with `stop + increment`, `increment` being 2 in this case